# Controlling multiple stepper motors using a single driver

Tags: arduino, motor, stepper-motor, motor-controller, stepper-driver

I want to control ~50 stepper motors using a single driver, and use only one Arduino pin to control each motor.

Currently I'm using a single A4988 driver and a couple of 12v 1amp stepper motors to prototype a part of a machine as a proof of concept, but I need to use many larger motors and better drivers in near future.

As I don't need motors to work simultaneously, I want to use a single driver to control them all.

I tried to validate my idea using 4 different relays and it seems that motors work perfectly as my needs (I tested and switched between them in a 24 hours long test). But as transistors are much cheaper and smaller in size, I want to use them if possible.

I have programming background and never designed a circuit before, but bellow is a schematics that I designed to control two stepper motors with a single driver, I don't know what kind of transistors or resistors should I use, or is this schematics possible at all? (As I mentioned, I already used a "4 relay module" instead of transistors and it worked well).

here is the schematics:

[image: Schematics of controlling multiple motors with one driver]

Any help to fix the schematics problems and choosing transistors and resistors would be appreciated.

Thanks.

p.s. As everyone in the comment section is suggesting to use multiple drivers I want to clear it again: Using multiple drivers is not an option, because I need to control larger motors and I need more expensive driver, which I can't afford many of them in a prototype. Any suggestion to use a single driver to control many motors, preferably using a single pin per motor is considerable. Thanks.

Comment: FETs would work better than BJTs here, but you have a problem in that the current goes both ways through those motor coils so you need a more sophisticated circuit to drive the transistors.  If you aren't driving the motors too fast, consider optical isolators instead.

Comment: Honestly, A4988s are not very expensive, and it will probably be easier in the end to just use independent drivers for each motor, and select them from the microcontroller side.

Comment: Agreed. Anything else is a bodge.

Comment: @evildemonic, I'll try to learn about FETs and optical isolators, thanks. Also, I know A4988 are not very expensive, but with larger motors, I need much more expensive drivers while they never work simultaneously, which means spending lots of $$$ for a prototype. Also each driver needs many pins on Arduino, which I can't spend these limited, precious pins for them ;) Thanks again.

Comment: your schematic diagram shows 5 data pins being used ... two drivers would use 6 data pins ... you may be able to use separate `enable` signals and connect the two `step` signals to one data pin ... same for the `direction` ... that would reduce the pin count to 4 pins or even 3 pins

Comment: i checked the data sheet ... you can connect the two enable pins to one data pin ... same with direction ... use separate `step` signals

Comment: @jsotola, AFAIK connecting enable pins will makes all stepper motors to draw a lot of power (As I need ~50 stepper motors). Also it needs a lot of $$$ for ~50 better drivers for larger motors and I can't afford it for a prototype (I don't live in a high-income country, and I'm not a millionaire). According to my schematics and tests using relays, I can power 50 steppers using a single driver and using 50+3 data pins on Arduino.

Comment: @antwon Your reasoning for not using mechanical relays is that they are more expensive. But you're planning on moving to larger motors. Wouldn't the price of the relays (which are usually very cheap) become irrelevant next to the price of each motor as you move to more expensive motors? "I have programming background and never designed a circuit before" seems a good reason for sticking to simpler circuits IMO.

Comment: @RaphaelP, yes your'e right. I think I was "premature optimizing" the circuit. My other problem was that I need too many relays for the job (~100 of them) which  takes a lot of space and are harder to maintain (as you see in the schematics above). I was  searching on google just now and I realized there are a kind of relay which is called DPDT. As you just said, I think it's better for me to go with DPDT relays because works just like 2 relays, but with fewer complexity and also is much easier for me. But I like science & it would be cool to know what other options are out there ;)

Comment: There is a potential complication that you should consider if you need to maintain precise position in between motor moves. Example: You set the relays to motor 1, move motor 1, switch the relays to motor 2, then move motor 2. Now you want to move motor 1 again, so you switch the relays back to 1. But, the controller and motor's phases may not match. You may need to move a few steps to re-synchronize. Your precise position has been lost. You will  need to decide if this is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented on the question, you're probably better off with conventional relays given that:

- their cost scales better as you go for larger/more powerful motors
- they are less complicated (since you stated that you've never
  designed a circuit before)

Having said that, if you wish to pursue the solid state approach then you're probably aiming at (MOS)FETs for their low resistance (R<sub>ds(on)</sub>) and low activation current (infinite gain at DC).

There's just one problem: power MOSFETs have an inherent diode in their construction (body diode) that prevents them from switching current both ways as your H-bridge driver requires. To solve that problem, you must use two of them back-to-back. By doing that, you've made yourself a simple Solid State Relay (SSR).

Here's how Texas Instruments explains it on their SSR design document:

[image: Source: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduc87a/tiduc87a.pdf]
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tiduc87a/tiduc87a.pdf

Looks like a good starting point for your pursuit.